# Coefficient of operator and how to do it

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, derivatives, taylor-expansion, generating-functions

This question stems from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1315060/question-about-the-coefficient-of-operator)
$$
\frac{1}{x+z}- \frac{1}{x} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k!}\frac{d^k}{dx^k}[\frac{1}{x}]
$$
Now, i need to find the Bell Polynomial of $\frac{1}{x}$,

$$
[z^n]\left(\frac{(-z)^k}{x^k(x+z)^k}\right) = [z^n]\sum_{n \geq k} Y^{\Delta}(n,k,x) z^n = \frac{k!}{n!} B_{n,k}(\frac{d}{dx}[\frac{1}{x}], \cdots,\frac{d^{n-k+1}}{dx^{n-k+1}}[\frac{1}{x}])
$$

$$
\frac{(-1)^k}{x^k} [z^n] z^k (x+z)^k = \frac{(-1)^k}{x^{k}} [z^n] (\frac{x}{z}+1)^{-k}
$$

$$
\frac{(-1)^k}{x^{k}} [z^n] (\frac{x}{z}+1)^{-k} = \frac{(-1)^k}{x^{k}} [z^n] \sum_{j=0}^\infty {-k \choose j} (\frac{x}{z})^j
$$

How do i take the coefficient of this power series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here's the calculation of $[z^n]$:
>
> \begin{align*}
> [z^n]\frac{(-z)^k}{x^k(x+z)^k}&=[z^n]\frac{(-z)^k}{x^{2k}\left(1+\frac{z}{x}\right)^k}\\
> &=\frac{(-1)^k}{x^{2k}}[z^n]\frac{z^k}{\left(1+\frac{z}{x}\right)^k}\\
> &=\frac{(-1)^k}{x^{2k}}[z^{n-k}]\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{z}{k}\right)^k}\tag{1}\\
> &=\frac{(-1)^k}{x^{2k}}[z^{n-k}]\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\binom{-k}{j}\left(\frac{z}{x}\right)^j\tag{2}\\
> &=\frac{(-1)^k}{x^{2k}}[z^{n-k}]\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\binom{k+j-1}{k-1}(-1)^j\left(\frac{z}{x}\right)^j\tag{3}\\
> &=\frac{(-1)^k}{x^{2k}}\binom{n-1}{k-1}(-1)^{n-k}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{n-k}\\
> &=\frac{(-1)^n}{x^{n+k}}\binom{n-1}{k-1}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the relationship $[z^n]z^k=[z^{n-k}]$ of the *coefficient of* operator
- In (2) we apply the *binomial series* expansion $(1+t)^\alpha=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\binom{\alpha}{j}t^j$ with $\alpha=-k$
- In (3) we apply the binomial coefficient identity $\binom{-n}{k}=\binom{n+k-1}{k}(-1)^k$

Comment: Okay, so now i have:

$$
\sum_{c=0}^n \sum_{k=c}^n \sum_{j=0}^{k-c} \sum_{l=1}^{n-1} {n \choose l}\frac{1}{j!} \frac{d^j}{df^j}[f^{k-c}] \frac{d^j}{d(\frac{1}{g})^j}[\frac{1}{g^c}] B_{l,k-c}^{\frac{1}{g}}(x) B_{n-l,c}^f(x)
$$

$$
B_{l,k-c}^{\frac{1}{g}}(x) = \frac{(-1)^l}{g(x)^{l-k+c}} {l-1 \choose k-c-1} B_{l,k-c}^g(x)
$$

Would this be correct?

Comment: @EricLawson: It looks quite ok. Nevertheless, I suggest you try to verify it for small values of $n$. Btw. you can upvote and/or accept an answer if you consider it useful. Best regards,

Comment: $$
B_{2,1}^{\frac{1}{g}}(x) = \frac{d^2}{dx^2}[\frac{1}{g}] = \frac{d}{dx}[\frac{-g'}{g^2}] = 2\frac{(g')^2}{g^3} - \frac{g''}{g^2}
$$
$$
B_{n,k}^{\frac{1}{g}}(x) = \frac{(-1)^n}{g(x)^{n+k}} {n-1 \choose k-1} B_{n,k}^g(x)
$$
Therefore with this logic:
$$
B_{2,1}^{\frac{1}{g}}(x) = (-1)^2\frac{1}{g^3} {1 \choose 0} B_{2,1}^g(x) = \frac{g''}{g^3}
$$
Which is clearly wrong

Comment: Oh i understand:

$$
Y^{\Delta}_{\frac{1}{g}}(n,k,x) = \frac{(-1)^n}{x^{n+k}}{n-1 \choose k-1}
$$

$$
Y^{\Delta}_{g(x)}(n,k,x) = \frac{k!}{n!}B_{n,k}^g(x)
$$

According to Theorem 6 in Kruchinin's the composita of $\frac{1}{g}$ is:
$$
Y^{\Delta}_{\frac{1}{g}}(n,k,x) = \sum_{j=k}^n Y^{\Delta}_{\frac{1}{x}}(j,k,x) Y^{\Delta}_{g(x)}(n,j,x)
$$

I will check this to see if it works with this new formula

Comment: $$
B_{2,1}^{\frac{1}{g}}(x) = \sum_{j=1}^2 \frac{(-1)^j}{g^{j+1}} {j-1 \choose 0} B_{2,j}^g(x) = -\frac{g''}{g^2} + \frac{(g')^2}{g^3}
$$

We are missing a constant, it should be:
$$
2\frac{(g')^2}{g^3} - \frac{g''}{g^2}
$$

Comment: I made an error in my last comment i meant to say:

Wait, i have a question on (3), why ${n+j-1 \choose k-1}$ why not:

$$
= \frac{(-1)^k}{x^{2k}} [z^{n-k}]\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} {k+j-1 \choose j} (-1)^j \left(\frac{z}{x}\right)^j
$$

Comment: @EricLawson: You could delete obsolete comments.

Comment: $$
\frac{d^2}{dx^2}[\frac{1}{g}] = \frac{d}{dx}[\frac{-g'}{g^2}] = 2\frac{(g')^2}{g^3} - \frac{g''}{g^2}
$$